# Images don't show after 8788 patch installed magento 1.8.1.0

Tags: magento, patch, magento-1.8

I am using Magento ver. 1.8.1.0.

The problem I am facing is when I installed SUPEE 8788 patch in my site, then when I am uploading images from admin, image is not uploaded, it is showing completed but didn't show anything.

When I revert back the patch, then it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The patch did deprecate the flash based uploader block.  More specific information on the various problems that were encountered with this patch can be found on the [Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140560/181).

It could be a problem with some extensions that you have installed.  There was a known problem, for example, with the CreareSEO Extension - https://github.com/adampmoss/CreareSEO/pull/78.

Comment: No, I am not using this CreareSEO Extension. Can you please help me out to sort out this problem

Comment: No one has applied SUPEE patch 8788 in  Magento ver. 1.8.1.0. ?

Comment: @Prince What extensions do you have installed?  Do any of them use the uploader?  Try looking for updates to your other extensions.

Comment: I have disabled each module one by one and checked by uploading image from admin but didn't solve the problem......

Comment: Also, I checked it the updates of all modules, but all are stable

Comment: can anyone please help me to get rid of this problem?